# Build products filter rang by custom fields - BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Price range filter already exist on the basic store. 
so when i search for products between 10$ - 100%

i got list of product from this url = `&min_price=10&max_price=100&category=1`

i want to do the same with values from custom fields (not product options), for example if i have 2 custom fields: 1. color 2. size

i want to build filter range by color or size, like this: `&custom_field_min_size=1&custom_field_max_size=2&category=1` (or color)

thank you.